# Length twig for string is miscounting

Tags: symfony, twig, drupal-8, twig-filter

Using twig function url('< current >') in a Drupal 8 template which one gives you the full URL, it prints 'http://192.168.0.133/drupal-8.5.2/home', but when I use the filter length it returns the value 3, and is not an array.

I can't length filter count some characters? I also tried to split it with delimiter '/' and returns null.

Comment: Yes it was an array, an associative array thats was what I failed, drupal use to return array and usefull field normally is using the key '#markup'

Comment: Post part of the code so we can understand better what might be the problem.